# How to expand the summation term with power?

Tags: summation, power-series

How to expand the following:

$$ \left( \sum^{M}_{m=0} \frac{x^{m}}{m!} \right)^{K} $$

where $M$ and $K$ are positive integers.

Comment: Well for large M, that is approximately $e^{Kx}$.

Comment: And for smaller $M$ it is just a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find in volume 2 of H.W. Goulds *[Combinatorial Identities](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.2.PDF)* in section 1.5 four variants of the *[Multinomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)*.

> Applying identity (1.76) we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\sum_{m=0}^{M}\frac{x^m}{m!}\right)^K
> =\sum_{k=0}^{K\cdot M}\sum_{\sum_{i=1}^Mi\cdot j_i=k}\binom{K}{j_0,j_1,\ldots,j_M}
> \frac{x^k}{(0!)^{j_0}(1!)^{j_1}\cdots(M!)^{j_M}}
> \end{align*}

with
\begin{align*}
\binom{K}{j_0,j_1,\ldots,j_M}=\frac{K!}{j_0!j_1!\cdots j_M!}\qquad\qquad \sum_{i=0}^Mj_i=K
\end{align*}
a *[multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)*.

Comment: what is identity (1.76) ?

Comment: @sky-light: Identity (1.76) in vol. 2 of H.W. Goulds book. Click the ref.

Comment: Thanks. So, $x^{k}$ remains the only variable in the expansion and the term   $ \sum_{k=0}^{K\cdot M}\sum_{\sum_{i=1}^Mi\cdot j_i=k}\binom{K}{j_0,j_1,\ldots,j_M}
\frac{1}{(0!)^{j_0}(1!)^{j_1}\cdots(M!)^{j_M}} $ can be determined seperatly depending on $K$. One more important question, do you have any algorithm or code that can be used to determine this term?

Comment: @sky-light: You're welcome! Yes, both statements are correct. Sorry, I've no SW-package or algorithm, which I could provide. Regards,